# How can i use the visual studio built-in database instead of this hard-coded data for my cascading dropdown?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, dropdown, cascading

I'm working on my first asp .net site, and I am making a cascading drop-down list.

I came across this code by stephen muecke [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym), and got it working, but was wondering how can i use my database(built in visual studio 2015) instead of the data hard coded into the Model.

```
public class Repository
    {
        public static List<City> FetchCities()
        {
            List<City> cities = new List<City>();
            cities.Add(new City() { ID = 1, Name = "Faridabaad" });
            cities.Add(new City() { ID = 2, Name = "Greater Noida" });
            return cities;
        }
        public static List<Locality> FetchLocalities()
        {
            List<Locality> localities = new List<Locality>();
            localities.Add(new Locality() { ID = 1, CityID = 1, Name = "East Faridabaad" });
            localities.Add(new Locality() { ID = 2, CityID = 2, Name = "West Faridabaad" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: By "built in" do you mean the install of SQL Server Express Edition that (sometimes) the Visual Studio installer gives you?

Comment: @Richard I didn't install anything aside from the visual studio, and by built-in, I meant this one right here.
[link](https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-59-creating-a-database-in-visual-studio)